# InkCanvas drawing getting out of scope

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

I have an InkCanvas control sized 400x250 in my UWP APP. I do not have any problems with drawing. However, when I get out of the scope of InkCanvas (which is 400x250) without releasing the pointer and keep drawing on other parts of the page InkCanvas still adds the ink.

I only want InkCanvas to get the ink from the part I specified for its width and height property. Is there any attiribute or method to achieve that?

Comment: Try to Clip tour canvas

Comment: Are you capturing the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using CoreInkIndependentInputSource's PointerPressing event to catch if user has draw anything on the surface but I do not think it's something related to it.

Eventually I ended up using Win2D library and some method named RenderAsync I found in the internet which calculates a surface are for the given InkCanvas width / height and saves the data to the specified StorageFile with the given background color, format and quality options.